# Setting an Ivy descriptor's status to "release" when publishing

Tags: ant, release, ivy

I am adding a `publish-release` target to my Ant build file. I would like to be able to run a build, and then optionally run the `publish-release` target to upload the files to my artifact server. So I tried the following:

```
<target name="publish-release">
    <ivy:resolve conf="*" />
    <ivy:publish resolver="releases">
        <ivy:artifacts pattern="${out.dir}/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" />
    </ivy:publish>
</target>
```

When I run this target the artifacts are uploaded properly, but the status in my Ivy descriptor file is `integration`. How can I change it to be `release`?

```
<!-- I would like the status here to be "release" -->
<info ... status="integration" publication="20141015084720"/>
```

I tried setting the `ivy.status` property to `release` but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My build was generating the Ivy descriptor with the `integration` status, and the `publish` step was just uploading that descriptor verbatim.

I added a `deliver` step to my `publish-release` task to regenerate the descriptor with the desired status:

```
<target name="publish-release">
    <ivy:resolve conf="*" />
    <ivy:deliver status="release" deliverpattern="${out.dir}/ivy-${project.version}.xml" />
    <ivy:publish resolver="releases">
        <ivy:artifacts pattern="${out.dir}/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" />
    </ivy:publish>
</target>
```